# Angular 5: Regex pattern should not allow alphanumerics/alphabet, it should allow only numbers

Tags: regex, validation, angular5

```
the Validators.pattern("Regex") should take any number but it should not allow the user to type any alphabet/alphanumeric value, no need of decimals either, it should allow only numeric values
```

validation message here in the template code!

```
 <ng-container id="NumericUpDown" *ngSwitchCase="5">
          <input type="number" [formControlName]="control.Name" [name]="control.Name" [id]="control.Id" [min]="control.Min" [max]="control.Max" step="1" [value]="control.Value">
              <span class ="tooltip-hint" *ngIf="control.Hint != null">{{control.Hint}}</span>
          <div *ngIf="form.controls[control.Name].invalid && (form.controls[control.Name].dirty || form.controls[control.Name].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <span *ngIf="form.controls[control.Name].errors.required">Please enter a valid value within the Range Limits.</span>
            <span *ngIf="form.controls[control.Name].errors.min">Entered value should be greater than Minimum allowed value.</span>
            <span *ngIf="form.controls[control.Name].errors.max">Entered value should be less than Maximum allowed value.</span>
            <span *ngIf="form.controls[control.Name].errors.pattern">Entered value should be only numbers, not in alphanumerics</span>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
```

logic:
   using Validators.Pattern() method here in order to pass the Regex string here. please suggest the pattern here to allow the numeric values in here

```
 private createFormControl(control: any): FormControl {
            let formControl: FormControl = null;
            switch (control.ControlType) {
              case ControlTypes.RadioButton:
              case ControlTypes.TextBox:
              case ControlTypes.DropDown:
              case ControlTypes.CheckBox:
                formControl = new FormControl({ value: control.Value || '', disabled: !control.Enabled });
                break;
              case ControlTypes.NumericUpDown:
                formControl = new FormControl(control.Value || '', this.configureValidators(control));
                break;
            }
            return formControl;
          }

          private configureValidators(control: any): Array<ValidatorFn> {
            const validators: Array<ValidatorFn> = new Array<ValidatorFn>();
            control.Validators.forEach(validator => {
              this.getValidator(validator, control).forEach(element => validators.push(element));
            });
            return validators;
          }

          private getValidator(ValidatorType: ValidatorTypes, control: any): Array<ValidatorFn> {
            switch (ValidatorType) {
              case ValidatorTypes.Required:
                return [Validators.required];
              case ValidatorTypes.Range:
                return [Validators.min(control.Min), Validators.max(control.Max)];
                case ValidatorTypes.Pattern:
                return [Validators.pattern("/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/")];
            }
          }
```

please suggest a regex pattern here Validators.pattern("/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/")

Comment: Try `Validators.pattern("-?(0|[1-9]\\d*)?")` if you need to disallow `0000` like inputs.

Comment: What exact problem are you facing? Do you just need a regex for the statement? In that case all other code you pasted is useless. Please clarify.

Comment: yeah i just need the regex statement, the suggestions was asking me to put the code so I kept the code

Comment: i dont want to disallow 0000s .. i just want the numeric up down not to take the alphabet/alphanumerics- i want the regex pattern

Comment: hi @ZiaUlRehmanMughal , could you answer this the regex pattern to be sent in the Validators.pattern(Regex pattern) here

Comment: @PadmajaVudatha Yes this is simple enough, please be specific with what kind of number you want to allow, include negatives? floats? any other formats of numbers? And update your question accordingly and i can help

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal ; the numbers can be negative or positive , no need of decimals the range is like this 100 to 10000 or 1 to 100000 anything it can accept excepts decimals and alphabet

Comment: In this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930957/javascript-regex-positive-negative-integers should solve your problem